# How to check zookeeper in cloudera vm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

For starting KAFKA we need to start **zookeeper**.but in cloudera VM i think there is zookeeper instance already running .**SO can anyone tell me how to check through VM terminal whether the default instance is runnig or not ?**
Also if we start a zookeeper service we can see the logger screen but how to check it for cloudera VM.

Thank You,

BISHNU

Answer (score 1):

In the Cloudera VM, you're running on a single node so running `zookeeper-client` should indicate if zookeeper is running.  If you see:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0]
```

it's running.  If you see this error looping:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

it's not running.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check via `netstat -tupln l grep 2181`